Keyboard Shortcut for Focusing on "places" option on Dolphin File manager
I use Fedora 40 KDE as my daily driver.
I was thinking of a keyboard shortcut that would let me focus on the places list in the Dolphin file manager.
Some would remind me of the key F9; however, what that does is show/hide the places option in the Dolphin. I am looking for a key map that would directly go to the places option. What I have been doing till now is using the mouse to hover over the places or keep hitting the tab button until I reach my desired option.
Is there any shortcut to achieve what I am looking for?
